# Powershell Export/Import-CLIXML suddenly failing (only in Powershell shell though)

Tags: powershell, credentials

Ok. This is strange and it has to have something to do with a policy that was applied in some form or fashion I just can't figure out what/where and I work in such a large organization that it's tough to find someone who can understand what is happening on my side enough to link it to something they did on their side.
Anyhow.. Exporting/Importing credentials with Export/Import-CLIxml stopped working. The strange part is it only stopped working in PowerShell Shell. It works fine if I try it from ISE.
Running both ISE and Powershell as an Administrator and executing the following CODE:

(get-credential) | export-clixml SomeNonExistentPathFile.xml ; $mycreds = import-CLIxml SomeNonExistentPathFile.xml ; $mycreds

In ISE the variable prints out the username/password as secure string as it should. In powershell i receive a warning in red that the import completed successfully with a message of NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Clixml], CryptographicException. And the variable is empty (however the file generated normally).
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you importing the CLIXML on the same computer, logged in as the same user?

Comment: Yes. Same User (as administrator) Same computer. But it effects all machines I've tried since last week ish. So it's not a "localized" issue. Again.. Exact same code, user, computer but different results in ISE than Powershell.

Comment: Did you change your password? That would break it.

Comment: Since it's working in ISE, what version of powershell is your 'shell'? Use `$PSVersionTable` to check `PSVersion` and `PSEdition`. Are you exporting and importing using the same version? If not, the xml file encoding could be the culprit if you've got some funky symbols.

Comment: Yes. Version is same on ISE and powershell.. 5.1.17763.1490/desktop. I'm pretty sure a password change is irrelevant at this point since powershell can't even read the variable for whatever reason. Obviously, a bad password would most certainly break it once I'm using that variable to do something. but at this point I'm just trying to make sure it is importing.

Comment: It looks like this is definitely attributed to McAfee. I found this reddit post with the same exact issue. https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/muyk58/help_with_importclixml.. Thanks for the suggestions everyone!

Comment: McAfee going above and beyond!  +1 for McAfee